# ReferenceError: prompt is not defined

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm trying to set a battleship game as a website for an assignment. In the assignment, prompt() is used.

I tried assigning a new value to the variable guess. That didn't work either. Here is what I have so far:

```
let location1 = 3; 
let location2 = 4;
let location3 = 5;

let guess;

let hits = 0;

let guesses = 0;

let isSunk = false;

while (isSunk == false) {
    guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number 0-6):");
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
        alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
        } else {
            guesses = guesses + 1;
    }
}
```

The game should provide with feedback of whether the ship has been hit or not, but all it does is prompting the "Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number 0-6):" message again and again.
When tested with the console, it will give ReferenceError: prompt is not defined.

Comment: Why do you think `prompt` should be defined? You haven't defined it. You also haven't specified what you are using to execute your JS so we can't know if you should expect your host environment to predefine it for you.

Comment: @Quentin I presume they're referring to `window.prompt`, except of course that's only available in browsers, and not in NodeJS.

Comment: Use "window.prompt" instead of prompt

Comment: Your code is behaving like it should .... the reason the prompt is appearing again and again is because isSunk is always false.

Comment: Use `break` to get out of the loop once your manipulation is done.

Comment: Thanks for helping, everyone!

Comment: I tried window.prompt() and that didn't change anything.

Comment: there is more code underneath that should change the value of isSunk if the ship gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows prompt is not defined then add this code at the start of the program:

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();
```